# Unable to get users by orgUnitPath with Admin SDK

Tags: google-apps-script, google-admin-sdk

Why am I unable to retrieve a list of users when using query to search the orgUnitPath? When I try the same parameters on the Google API Explorer (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users/list) the response returns the expected result of users. However, in my code, the response returned is undefined because the full response does not seem to be pulled. Code.gs for reference:

```
function myFunction() {
  var options = {
    domain: schoolDomain, // Google Workspace domain name
    query: orgUnitPath='/School Staff',
    type: 'all',
    maxResults: 5,
    orderBy: 'familyName',
    viewType: 'admin_view'
  };

  var response = AdminDirectory.Users.list(options);
  console.log(response.users);
}
```

Comment: I figured out the solution, this should be better documented. The query parameter needs to be wrapped in quotes. The line: query: orgUnitPath='/School Staff' should be written as query: "orgUnitPath='/School Staff'"

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing this answer as a community wiki since the solution was provided by the OP in the comments section.

The issue was related to the syntax of the query, when using the `query` for `orgUnitPath`, it needs to be  inside `''` like this:

```
"orgUnitPath='/School Staff'"
```

or

```
'orgUnitPath="/School Staff"'
```

This information can be found in the Google Documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/search-users).